# What is the better way of beveling this part so it looks better?

Tags: vertices, bevel

I was trying to create a shield. I beveled the top part.

[image: This is how it looks in Blender.]

It looks bad when I paint it.

[image]

How can I create the top part so it looks better when I paint?

Comment: what does it give if you right click > Shade Smooth and enable Auto Smooth?

Comment: https://ibb.co/L1FmJsV This is how it looks.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It fails to download. Is the link I sent broken? Can you see it from there?

Comment: Suggestion.  Perhaps you can place an example of some mesh that would be your goal in the question.  Typically this site wants to see goals rather than stating [looks better].  I do not know what your goal is, perhaps others do.  If I venture to guess ... If your model is simple, I suggest start afresh ... more loop cuts and proportional editing.

Comment: Please Consider also Shade Smooth.  The famous video website that has a name that rhymes with noonoob has many tutorials on ... loop cuts, proportional editing, and shade smooth.

Comment: or use another platform like workupload.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this look like what you try to achieve?

If it's the case, a bevel of only the top segment and auto smooth did the job.

[image]